# Redirecting all traffic from HTTP_REFERER to something else

Tags: .htaccess

Someone is scraping a friends blog, word for word, picture for picture.

I am trying some code out in htaccess so that when they do this in the future they will scrape some fake content.

Here is what I have at the moment.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.theirdomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/rickrolling.html [R=301,L]
```

I want the scraping domain to always see the rickrolling.html page when they scrape.

Had a look on here and the examples I found don't seem to work. Above seems like it should work for me.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When they're scraping, do they actually set their own domain name as the HTTP `Referer` header? I suspect not. You'd be better off checking against their IP address or something. Do you have access to the server logs? Can you identify the requests that are coming from them?

But ultimately, you're here looking for a technical solution to a legal problem. You'd be better off doing a `whois` lookup on their domain name, and threatening to sue them and their host. If both you and their host are in the USA, there's a special legal tool called a DMCA Takedown Notice. I'm not in the USA myself, so I don't know much about it. But look it up.

Comment: Yeah we're looking at doing that too, although I have been told that the site has false details in the whois.